# Passing a variable from PHP-generated list to jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, variables

I have a PHP-generated list:

```
<?php $row_number = 0;  
 while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $row_number++;      
    $movie_id = $row->movie_id;
    $title = $row->title;

if ($num_rows>0){ ?>
    <p class='dragelement' id="<?php echo $movie_id; ?>">
    <?php echo $title; ?> 
    </p>
<?php } 
} ?>
```

and am trying to pass the variable 'movie_id' to jQuery for a drag-and-drop function using the id of the parent p selector:

```
var parent = $("p.dragelement").closest('p');
var movie_id = parent.attr('id');
```

The problem is that the resulting value of 'movie_id' is the first one of the list, not the current one.

Any ideas much appreciated!

Comment: var parent = $("p.dragelement").closest('p'); will always return the first element => Improve your selector. If you have no idea how, post your drag/drop JS code

Comment: Please show your HTML output.

Comment: Art2's var parent = $(".dragelement:last") did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about last selector? 
http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

```
var parent = $(".dragelement:last");
var movie_id = parent.attr('id');
```